# Eval with complex business child object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class Employee with fields Name and OfficeAddress.OfficeAddress again is an object of type Address.
Address is a class with fields Building,City and Country.
I have list of employee called empList.Now I want to bind this empList to a gridview so that it should display Name,Building,City and Country.
The problem is gridview cannot find properties Building,City and Country in empList when I bind gridview using Eval("Building") or Eval("City") or Eval("Country").Please provide me the syntax to bind these columns.

Comment: Have you tried `Eval("OfficeAddress.Building")`?